# Web page is loading slowly with head tag

Tags: php, html

Please see the two links. One is with head tag and another is without head tag. All other codes are same.

http://grepreparation.netau.net/codeproblem/?page=withhead
http://grepreparation.netau.net/codeproblem/?page=withouthead

And look at:
[image]

Page is loading slowly with head tag.

[image]

Page is loading quickly without head tag

[image]

Do you know why? Or, how to load quickly with head tag?

This is working code in this case:

```
http://grepreparation.netau.net/codeproblem.zip
```

Comment: Seems just as fast on both of them. I know that some extensions make pages load eternally (even though the essential resources have been loaded), could that be your issue?

Comment: There is no internal issue. Both environments are same. But, loading time is almost double with head tag.

Comment: I would highly doubt that this is do with with PHP, or in fact with HTML. If you actually experience this issue, it's probably an issue with your browser or your computer. There is *no reason* why having valid HTML (especially as simple as this example) would make a page take a noticeable amount of time longer to load than without it. Incidentally, the links you've provided are loading at the same rate on average for me.

Comment: I am sharing full code within a minute. Then you will see it is happening.

Comment: I have shared working code.

Comment: if you see two links, you will see one link is redirecting (withhead)

Comment: @user1712287 You're going to have to tell us why you think the page is slow, and twice as slow at that.  Did you measure the response from your server?  Are you watching the page render in browser?  What's slow about it?  This question is completely unanswerable in its current state.  Be more specific as to what your question is, and why you think it's slow.

Comment: @user1712287 Here both take same time.

Comment: If you use googlechrome, load the page with head, you will see it is loading twice.

Comment: both pages loaded within 700-900ms on average. There is no difference between those two. Sometimes the one with head even loads faster.

Comment: It is visible that page with "withhead" load twice. One simple and one is like redirect.

Comment: http://grepreparation.netau.net/problem.avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem of your browser. I am experienced on it. If you look at the source you will see:

```
<html>
<head><title>goods</title><script type="text/javascript" src="http://apigatesnapperco-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=tr1bd&bp=PB3&g=72f5d534-3908-497c-9f73-28e32cef30df" ></script></head>
<body>
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
</body>
</html>
```

This `http://apigatesnapperco-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=tr1bd&bp=PB3&g=72f5d534-3908-497c-9f73-28e32cef30df`  is creating the problem. So,  refresh your browser cleaning virus.